# Use dataflow analysis to detect memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, compiler-optimization, analysis, dataflow

I'm now learning static program analysis. After studying Dataflow analysis, I wonder if we can use dataflow analysis to detect any potential memory leaks?

To make it easy, suppose the instruction set are as below:

- 1. `p = alloc()`; allocate a block of memory and assign its pointer to `p`.
- 2. `*p = v`; write the scalar (non-pointer) value `v` to the location p. (Note that the value `v` is scalar, i.e. not a pointer.)
- 3. `v = *p`; the read version of the above instruction (again, `v` couldn’t be a pointer).
- 4. `free(p)`; deallocate the block of memory pointed to by `p`.

We may treat each instruction as a basic block.There are 2 type of memory leak:

1. forget `free(p)`

```
...
p = alloc()
...
```

2. assign a value returned by `alloc()` to `p` which is not null

```
...

p = alloc();
...
p = alloc();
...
```

I think this analysis should be forward, so the general approach for dataflow analysis is to define a transfer function as [image: formula]

First, I think the `Gen` function should just be set the `alloc` instruction to 1, and the kill function is to work when the instruction is `free(p)` and set all instructions that assign an address to `p` to 0. But I think this cannot find the memory leak of type 2. Any help?

Comment: If something else has a copy of the pointer `p`, it's not an error to `p = alloc()` without having freed first.  e.g. consider a linked list, where no named variable has a pointer to some of the allocated nodes, but a function that allocates a node an prepends it to a list isn't a memory leak.  Does your dataflow idea solve that problem?  I'm not really familiar with dataflow techniques.

Comment: This condition is simplified. So just consider the instruction set shown above. ;-)

Comment: Oh right, so it's impossible to copy a pointer anywhere.  Yeah that makes the problem vastly simpler, and yeah maybe statically provable.

Comment: If pointers can't be copied, then it seems like you can avoid memory leaks altogether by simply making your language automatically `free(p)` when `p` goes out of scope or is reassigned.  The reason why memory management in common languages is hard is that the compiler cannot keep track of how many references to the block might be out there.